# C# Add User data to Local Database - Parsing Error

Tags: c#, database, parsing, local, sqlexception

I'm trying to add User Input to a Local Database, using testboxes, comboboxes, a checkbox, a checkedlistbox and datapickers and it's really not playing ball.

I get a `SQLException` unhandled error stating

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 261,Token in error = End ]' at the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

My code is below, does anybody have an idea where I have gone wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO OMTracker (ProjectNumber, ProjectTitle, ProjectDescription, Client, EndUser, ContractManager, Engineer, DocumentsNeeded, CompletedDate, IssuedDate, ContractDiary, Revision, Comments) VALUES (@ProjectNumber, @ProjectTitle, @ProjectDescription, @Client, @EndUser, @ContractManager, @Engineer, @DocumentsNeeded, @CompletedDate, @IssuedDate, @ContractDiary, @Revision, @Comments)";

    string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\OMTrackerDatabase.sdf;Persist Security Info=True";

    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
    string Documents = DocumentsNeeded.CheckedItems.ToString();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectNumber", ProjectNumber.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectTitle", ProjectTitle.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDescription", ProjectDescription.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", Client.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndUser", EndUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractManager", ContractManager.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Engineer", Engineer.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentsNeeded", Documents);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Revision", Revision.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompletedDate", CompletedDate.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssuedDate", IssuedDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractDiary", ContractDiary.Checked ? 1 : 0);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", Comments.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          

    MessageBox.Show("Entry Added.");
    this.Close();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does `DocumentsNeeded.CheckedItems.ToString()` turn into?  Also, have you looked at profiler to see the query that you've generated?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It turns a number of checked items in the CheckedListBox into a string so that it can be used as a Parameter Value. My apologies, I'm sort of new to coding, what is a profiler?

Comment: What are the C# types of Engineer.SelectedValue and ContractManager.SelectedValue ? What are the SQL dataTable types of  Engineer, ContractManager and  ContractDiary ?

Comment: Hi Graffito. 'Engineer' is a combobox and is a Combobox type on the DataTable. Same for 'ContractManager'. ContractDiary is a Checkbox and is a Checkbox Type of the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompletedDate", CompletedDate.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssuedDate", IssuedDate.Text);
```

--I would guess that you are trying to put a string into a datetime field for IssuedDate.

Comment: Hi NeutralHandle. Can't believe I overlooked that. However i'm still getting a SqlCeException was unhandled error with the same error message.

Comment: ProjectNumber should probably be a numeric type and it is being passed a string value.

Comment: ProjectNumber can start with a letter followed by a 4 digit number, so it can't be numeric type, it'll have to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It didn't like the 'SelectedValue' as the Parameter Value of the @ContractManager and @Engineer, so I changed it to 'SelectedItem' and it worked perfectly.

Thank you for your suggestions non-the less.